# Rails + Ember + Ember Data empty JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

What is the current best solution to fix the problem that rails respond_with returns an empty body with status 200 on successful PUT requests, but Ember (JQuery) expects a valid JSON response, therefore javascript warnings are shown?

I could of course replace respond_with in the rails code with if/render/then/render/end, however that loses the brevity and I would prefer not to do that. I have been checking and in some places I read that this should already be fixed in JQuery, but with the below versions I still get the same problem.

```
Ember      : 1.5.1
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a
Handlebars : 1.3.0
jQuery     : 1.11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, Rails PUT requests. Best I came up with was to fill in the response myself, like so:

```
def update
  book = Book.find(params[:id])

  updated_book = BookUpdater.new(book, user: current_user).update(permitted_params)
  respond_with do |format|
    if updated_book.errors.present?
      format.json { render json: { errors: updated_book.errors }, status: 422 }
    else
      format.json { render json: updated_book, status: :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

Gotta keeps the Embers happy.